# ROS with rtabmap : can't launch rtabmap tutorial

Tags: ubuntu, ros, google-project-tango

)

**OS**: Ubuntu 16.04 64 Bit

**ROS**: Lunar (tried Kinetic before) Desktop Full

**rtabmap version** : 0.13.2

My approach ist to use the rtabmap feature in cooperation with Tango ROS Streamer which is already running fine.

I followed the instructions on this tutorial :

http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutor...

At step 6 it fails at this command

```
rosrun rtabmap_ros pointcloud_to_depthimage cloud:=/tango/point_cloud camera_info:=/tango/camera/color_1/camera_info _fixed_frame_id:=start_of_service _decimation:=8 _fill_holes_size:=5
```

with the error:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named pointcloud_to_depthimage below /opt/ros/lunar/share/rtabmap_ros
```

I already installed rtabmap via:

```
sudo apt install ros-lunar-rtabmap-ros
```

additionally i attached the setup.bash file for ros to my ~/.bashrc and updated rosdep...

What could go wrong ? -_-

best regards and many thanks in advance for any help

Mark

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

it seems the aptitude package is not containing the nodelets. After installing rtabmap from source as well as rtabmap_ros it worked like a charm :-)

- Setup Catkin Workspace : http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace
- Install rtabmap including rtabmap_ros:  https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap_ros-
- Adding ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash to ~/.bashrc